# git-svn not checking out the latest revision

Tags: git-svn

I initialized a new git project via git svn clone  and the version git checked out is not the latest.  Am I running the command incorrectly?  I simply ran git svn clone  is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the project I checked out is part of a larger repository.  SVN shows where the respository is at which was larger (newer) than the directory I had checked out.